# "Exception thrown: write access violation. **_Left** was 0xCCCCCCCC." Why will my function call properly only with certain values?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a number conversion program that will take a decimal, hex, or binary number and convert it into a different type. This program will assign an enumerated value for the original number type and the type to covert to, and assign them to int variables. These variables are passed in a function call, along with the number to convert.

My code so far is as follows:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    
    using namespace std;
    void convert(int numType, int conversionType, string userNum);
    
    
    
    int main()
    {
        cout << "What type of number would you like to provide?\n";
        cout << "Decimal(1), Binary(2), Hexadecimal(3)\n";
        
        int numType;
        
        cin >> numType;
        
        if (numType < 1 || numType > 3)
        {
            cout << "Please enter an appropriate value.\n";
            cin >> numType;
        }
    
        string userNum;
        
        cout << "Please enter the number.\n";
    
        cin >> userNum;
    
        int conversionType;
        cout << "What type of number would you like to convert to?\n";
        if (numType == 1)
        {
            cout << "Binary(2) or Hexadecimal(3)\n";
            cin >> conversionType;
            if (conversionType < 2 || conversionType > 3)
            {
                cout << "Please enter an appropriate value.\n";
                cin >> conversionType;
            }
        }
        else if (numType == 2)
        {
            cout << "Decimal(1) or Hexadecimal(3)\n";
            cin >> conversionType;
            if (conversionType < 1 || conversionType == 2 || conversionType > 3)
            {
                cout << "Please enter an appropriate value.\n";
                cin >> conversionType;
            }
        }
        else if (numType == 3)
        {
            cout << "Decimal(1) or Binary(2)\n";
            cin >> conversionType;
            if (conversionType < 1 ||conversionType >2)
            {
                cout << "Please enter an appropriate value.\n";
                cin >> conversionType;
            }
        }
        cout << "The conversion yeilds: ";
        convert(numType, conversionType, userNum);
        
    return 0;
    }
    
    void convert(int numType, int conversionType, string userNum)
    {
        int num = stoi(userNum);
    
        if (numType == 1 && conversionType == 2)
        {
            int binNum[64];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; num > 0; i++)
            {
                binNum[i] = (num % 2);
                num /= 2;
            }
            
            for (i -= 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                cout << binNum[i];
            }
                cout << endl;
        }
    
        if (numType == 1 && conversionType == 3)
        {
            string hexNum[64];
            int i = 0;
    
            while (num != 0)
            {
                int tempVal;
    
                tempVal = (num % 16);
    
                if (tempVal < 10)
                {
                    num += 48;
                }
                else
                {
                    num += 55;
                }
    
                hexNum[i] = num;
    
                i++;
                num /= 16;
            }
            for (i -= 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                cout << hexNum[i];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

When I test this using numType = 1 and conversionType = 2 (decimal to binary) all works well.
However, when I use numType = 1 and conversionType = 3 I get this error.

Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.

```
    **_Left** was 0xCCCCCCCC. occurred
```

and in xstring file I see this:

```
     static _CONSTEXPR17 void assign(_Elem& _Left, const _Elem& _Right) noexcept {
            _Left = _Right;
        }
```

Could anyone help me understand why, when conversionType is 3 this error is thrown and not when it is 2?
I have tested to make sure that conversionType actually stores the value before the function call.

EDIT: The advice to remove all irrelevant code was very useful as I see the error is not with the function call as I had assumed. It is in the conversion formula for hex. As Igor pointed out, I messed up the formula and when I put in a fix the exception is no longer thrown. I honestly cant recall a good reason as to why I thought the error was in the function call but I am at a novice level after all. Thank you all for taking the time to look at my question and to comment.

Comment: This is way too much code. Remove code until you have the smallest example you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem. Hint: get rid of all the prompts and all the options. Just do the conversion that fails. Should be about half a dozen lines of code.

Comment: If you're using visual studio then `0xCCCCCCCC` indicates uninitialised stack memory. Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: And please post code that compiles. This code does not.

Comment: `num` never becomes zero because you keep adding 48 or 55 to it on every iteration of the loop. Eventually, `i` becomes equal 64, and `hexNum[i]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. You might have meant to adjust `tempVal` instead. It's also not clear why you use an array of strings, where each string stores just a single character. You can easily store a sequence of characters in a single string - that's kinda what it exists for.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I didn't copy enough text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** seems you figured it out while i was writing answer.

explantion in the bottom of answer.
you should replace this:

```
if (numType == 1 && conversionType == 3)
{
    string hexNum[64];
    int i = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        int tempVal;
        tempVal = (num % 16);
        if (tempVal < 10)
        {
            num += 48;
        }
        else
        {
            num += 55;
        }
        hexNum[i] = num;
        i++;
        num /= 16;
    }
    for (i -= 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << hexNum[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

to this:

```
if (numType == 1 && conversionType == 3)
{
    string hexNum[64];
    int i = 0;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        int tempVal;
        tempVal = (num % 16);
        if (tempVal < 10)
        {
            tempVal += '0'; // tempVal instead num and not use magic constant
        }
        else
        {
            tempVal += 'A' - 10; // tempVal instead num and not use magic constant
        }
        hexNum[i] = tempVal; // tempVal instead num
        i++;
        num /= 16;
    }
    for (i -= 1; i >= 0; i--) // >= instead > to not cut last hex digit
    {
        cout << hexNum[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Explanation: you use `num` instead `tempVal`, so anyway `num` was increased by at least 16 (in one case 48 i other case 55), so when u divide `num` by 16 it **never** becomes **zero**, so `i` increases until `haxNum[i]` lies out of your stack and `0xCCCCCCCC` was thrown.

Same explanation wrote @Igor Tandetnik in comments.

@Alan Birtles was right that it's stack acess issue

Comment: `Explanation: u use` -- Do not use phone shortcuts when answering a question.  The reason why is that there are persons who's native language is not English, and putting things like "u" instead of "you" makes the answer more difficult to understand for those persons.  Also, the answer should look as professional as possible, and not something that looks like street lingo.